# Reduce the image size without losing its quality in photoshop

Tags: resize, photoshop

I am having an image which is taken as a screenshot and it should be uploaded in my webpage, so I wanted to edit it through Photoshop. As I am new to Photoshop, please help me to find a way. Thanks in advance!

- I want the image size (height & width) to be reduced
- I want the image to be without losing quality

How to resize this image without losing its quality, through in Photoshop? 
[image: The image is 1.36MB]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shrink image without losing quality in 3 ways:

1. **Photoshop**:

   - Launch Photoshop then click on **image** > **image size**. Now you can select width and height as per your choice. Don't forget to tick on **Bicubic sharper (reduction)**.
2. **Microsoft Paint**:

   - First of all, launch Paint and then select **resize**. And now you can adjust width and height of your images.
3. **Online Tools**: There are numerous websites available across the web by which you can easily shrink all your images without losing quality.

Reference:
http://www.hugestreet.info/2016/12/shrink-images-without-losing-quality.html

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to reduce the size of an image without reducing quality unless it is a vector file.

You might be able to convert/export it as a .pdf in photoshop. I know you can in Gimp.

Comment: is there a way to convert an image to a vector file..?